# How to get only URL from a string

Tags: python, html, string, url, formatting

`https://www.some.com/7e3a729f86efd33fe9c727b02cdcc44692bf8520?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.danforthmainstreetclinic.ca%2F`

*How to get only* **danforthmainstreetclinic.ca**

*link always change like this*: `https://www.some.com/8343b54b1a55dbf1a003af0d0c7e9ba4ea762245?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2F782596948538540`

Need only **facebook.com/782596948538540**

how to format `%2F = /` , `%3A= :` or other format.

Comment: try `url.split('redirect=')[-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
import urllib.parse
url = "https://www.some.com/8343b54b1a55dbf1a003af0d0c7e9ba4ea762245?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2F782596948538540".split('redirect=')[-1]
print(urllib.parse.unquote(url))
```

**Output:**

> http://facebook.com/782596948538540

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unquote` from `urllib.parse`

which replaces `%xx` escapes with their single-character equivalent.

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
res = unquote(url).split('redirect=')[-1]
```

---

**res:**

```
'http://facebook.com/782596948538540'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this straight forward answer:

```
url = 'https://www.some.com/8343b54b1a55dbf1a003af0d0c7e9ba4ea762245? 
redirect=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2F782596948538540'
url_split = url.split('%')
new_url  = url_split[-2].strip('2F') + '/'+ url_split[-1].strip('2F')
print(new_url)
```

> $ facebook.com/782596948538540

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
import re

urls = [
    "https://www.some.com/7e3a729f86efd33fe9c727b02cdcc44692bf8520?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.danforthmainstreetclinic.ca%2F",
    "https://www.some.com/8343b54b1a55dbf1a003af0d0c7e9ba4ea762245?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2F782596948538540"
]

pattern = r'.+http%3A%2F%2F(.+)'
regex = re.compile(pattern)

for url in urls:
    matched = regex.match(url);
    if (matched):
        found_url = matched.groups()[0]
        print(re.sub(r'%2F', '/', found_url))
```

```sh
www.danforthmainstreetclinic.ca/
facebook.com/782596948538540
```